# how to get data back from onPostExecute

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, matrixcursor

I have a class which is implementing `FilterQueryProvider` and having an inner class which is extending `AsyncTask`. I am using this inner class to call a REST API and getting data successfully in `onPostExecute` which is `MatrixCursor`. But I want this `MatrixCursor` data in `runQuery()` method of outer class.

I am calling REST API in `onCreate` method. How can I get it in `runQuery` method???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `matrixcursor` in the Activity class, initiate it on onCreate and use the same in the inner class. you can then access and modify if from inner async task and access it from activity class. 
Ex.

```
mAsyncTask.execute(....);
mAsyncTask.get();
runQuery();
```

Comment: But problem is that when i use it in `runQuery` its showing count 0.Means data is getting loaded after method call.

Comment: Use `yourAsyncTask.get();` to get the result. This will wait for `doInbackground()` to complete. You can then run `runQuery`

Comment: can i pass `matrixcursor` in place of `cursor` as argument in a method?